# Catch all translated texts on a page before interpolation

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

> Trying to create a possibility for admins to change translations on
>   the current page without editing language files directly.

I'm using angular-translate and I want to catch all translated texts on a current page before interpolation. What I need:

```
translationId: original-value-without-interpolation
```

First I changed the translate filter and wrote a custom interpolator to return an object instead of just the interpolated value.

```
interpolate: function (string, interpolateParams) {
    return {
        string: string,
        interpolateParams: interpolateParams,
        translated: $translateDefaultInterpolation.interpolate(string, interpolateParams)
    };
}
```

Then inside the translate filter I was able to access both the `translationId` and `original-value`.

Soon after that I remembered that I had forgotten everything about directives and who knows what else I might have forgotten that use the same interpolator.

Now it feels like it would be safer to find an alternative where I can catch the `translationId` and the `original-value` without editing filters and directives.

Is there perhaps a function that I can hook myself to that I haven't found yet?

Bear in mind that I only want to catch the translations on the current page and I need to get them before {{values}} are replaced.

- angular 1.2.28
- angular-translate 1.5.2

---

**Edit**: Apparently I can access to the translations table `$translateProvider.translations()` where I can get values before interpolation. Then I would only need to track down all the translations used on the current page. (**Edit2**: Unable to access the $translationTable at runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

First thing I did was to create a custom loader. Which is based on the default one but it also stores all the loaded translations into an object. Which is later passed on.

Secondly I created a `translate` filter and directive. Which are also pretty much based on the provided one put with an addition of:

**Filter**

```
angular.module('app')

.filter('translate', ['$parse', '$translate', 'TranslationsHandler', function ($parse, $translate, TranslationsHandler) {

    var translateFilter = function (translationId, interpolateParams, interpolation) {

        if ( ! angular.isObject(interpolateParams)) {
            interpolateParams = $parse(interpolateParams)(this);
        }

        TranslationsHandler.addViewTranslation($translate.use(), translationId);

        return $translate.instant(translationId, interpolateParams, interpolation);
    };

    // Since AngularJS 1.3, filters which are not stateless (depending at the scope)
    // have to explicit define this behavior.
    translateFilter.$stateful = true;

    return translateFilter;
}]);
```

---

**Directive**

```
angular.module('app')

.directive('translate', ['TranslationsHandler', '$translate', function (TranslationsHandler, $translate) {

    return {
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            TranslationsHandler.addViewTranslation($translate.use(), attrs.translate);
        }
    };

}]);
```

Both of these have the addition of `TranslationsHandler.addViewTranslation`

Since I mentioned that I'm trying to make it possible to change translations on page the translations object looks like this:

```
var stuff = {
    file: {}, // Data loaded from translation files
    server: {}, // Already changed & saved translations but not yet merged with files
    changed: {}, // Currently changed translations
    current: {}, // Current view translations
    merged: {} // All together in this order: file + server + changed
}
// When in translation mode, the merged array is the one passed to angular-translate as the translation table
// Also on state change I clear the current object so that I can fill that up again
// And I use  $injector.get('$translate').refresh() this after every blur event on the input to change the translation. This way I am able to display the change on the page.
```

Comment: While your filter is stateless, I believe, you don't have to mark it as such: 1. Its behavior does not change between calls, right? 2. It only needs to be invoked once per language and key, so that you can collect the keys, right? So it has state, but there's no way for angular to find it out.

Comment: I guess, I was wrong. Your filter is not statefull because of what it's doing in addition to translating, but because of the translation being dependent on global state.

Comment: @maaartinus I guess I simply copied 1:1 from the original translate filter and added just the `TranslationHandler.addViewTranslation`. But I just checked the definition for $stateless and I guess you're right.